# How can I test a germinating pea seed for the presence of maltose?

Tags: photosynthesis, experiment, germination

I need to do a simple experiment to test whether germinating pea seeds produce maltose for the breakdown of starch into simple sugars.

Comment: Iodine. Thre is a reputed classic experiment, wait for while

Comment: for breakdown they does not produce maltOse but they produce moltAse, also known as amylase. Alpha-amylase is common in seed, it helps supply food (simple sugar) to pre-photosynthetic seedling

Comment: Here it is, I can't remember the inventors right-now, if I could find them, I'll inform immediately. http://www.tankonyvtar.hu/en/tartalom/tamop412A/2011_0009_Levai_Laszlo_Veres_Szilvia-Applied_Plant_Physiology/ch13.html ; URL: http://www.tankonyvtar.hu/en/tartalom/tamop412A/2011_0009_Levai_Laszlo_Veres_Szilvia-Applied_Plant_Physiology/images/062.png. , and https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/sCX8V2iMGT47fmE4Xw-LNmBRjBUE4Edko3zPHhR6ii0y612AekZT14p9--C3Ce2h8mIWdw=s170 . In this website the inventors' name is not found

Comment: DNSA colorimetric assay is another popular method to test amylase activity.